# How do I download a workbook object as a .xlsx file in a shiny app?

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I have a shiny app where a user uploads an excel file, and can then download their uploaded file with some additional cells added containing information on the analysis done on the file. I'm trying to figure out how to do this download with a `workbook` object instead  of a `data.frame` object because I'm planning on using the `xlsx` package to fill certain cells with certain colors based on the analysis of the row. My understanding of `data.frame` objects has led me to believe that they are not able to contain information that would color a cell when downloaded as a .xlsx file. Here's a simplified version of my code:

Server:

```r
output$download <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "flagged.xlsx",
        content = function(file) {
            write_xlsx(wb, path = file)
        }
    )
```

UI:

```r
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Example"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            downloadButton("download", "Download Flagged Excel")
        )
    )
))
```

This code doesn't work if wb is a `workbook` object (and I get why, the documentation states that this function takes a `data.frame` object). How can I download the file in a way that will let me do some server-side styling of the cells? Is it possible to download a workbook object, or is there another data type out there that can preserve the formatting of the cells? Thanks!

Comment: You could use the DT package which has an extension that downloads to .xlsx. See the Buttons section here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

Comment: So I am guessing you are trying to apply some formatting to the data file uploaded by user?